# php Query join tables

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

In my Joomla component I have two table:

Table1: #__com_units

```
 Id | unit | posx | posy 
 ------------------------
  1 | 001A | 100 | 200
  2 | 002A | 101 | 202
  3 | 003A | 102 | 204
  4 | 004A | 103 | 206
  5 | 005A | 104 | 208
```

Table1: #__com_reservations

```
 Id | unit |     From    |     To    | Mood (dropdown with value of Avaliable and Rented)
 --------------------------------------------
  1 | 001A | YYYY-MM-DD | YYYY-MM-DD |Available
  2 | 002A | YYYY-MM-DD | YYYY-MM-DD |Rented
  3 | 003A | YYYY-MM-DD | YYYY-MM-DD |Available
  3 | 004A | YYYY-MM-DD | YYYY-MM-DD |Available
  3 | 005A | YYYY-MM-DD | YYYY-MM-DD |Rented
```

i want two get two query to show the result as buttons, but its not working:

**1) One for Rented units**

```
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
  $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'unit', 'mood', 'posx', 'posy')));
  $query->from($db->quoteName('#__com_units', '#__com_reservations'));
  $query->where($db->quoteName('unit')." = ".$db->quote('1'),'AND')     
  ->where($db->quoteName('mood')." = ".$db->quote('rented'));
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $results = $db->loadObjectList();
  foreach ($results as $result)
  {
  echo '<button class=" ' . $result->mood . ' ' . $result->posx . ' ' . $result->posy . '" value=' . $result->id . ' disabled> ' . $result->unit  . '</button>';
 }
```

**2)One for Avaliable units**

```
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
  $query->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'unit', 'mood', 'posx', 'posy')));
  $query->from($db->quoteName('#__com_units', '#__com_reservations'));
  $query->where($db->quoteName('unit')." = ".$db->quote('1'),'AND')     
  ->where($db->quoteName('mood')." = ".$db->quote('available'));
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $results = $db->loadObjectList();
  foreach ($results as $result)
  {
  echo '<button class=" ' . $result->mood . ' ' . $result->posx . ' ' . $result->posy . '" value=' . $result->id . ' disabled> ' . $result->Unit  . '</button>';
 }
```

**3)And what if i want to have one query for rented units when they have valid date range?**

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this if you want to get result from two tables combined

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db->getQuery(true);
  $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
  $query->select($db->quoteName(array('a.unit', 'b.mood', 'a.posx', 'a.posy')));

  $query->from($db->quoteName('#__com_units', 'a'));
  $query->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__com_reservations', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.unit') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.unit') . ')');
```

REST OF YOUR QUERY
You are doing unit = 1, I dont know how as unit is given as 001A, 002A etc. If you follow the above syntax there wont be any error.

Comment: `$query->where($db->quoteName('b.floor')." = ".$db->quoteName('a.floor'),'AND')->where($db->quoteName('b.building')." = ".$db->quoteName('a.building'),'AND') ->where($db->quoteName('a.confirmation')." = ".$db->quote('yes'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($results as $result)
  {
echo '<button class=" ' . $result->mood . ' ' . $result->position_row . ' ' . $result->position_column . '" value=' . $result->id . ' disabled> ' . $result->unit  . '</button>';}` tnx updated and continued with this code there is no error but result is blank!!

Comment: plese see my new post for this question with much detailed. [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589564/php-query-inner-join-tables/37591285#37591285)