# php Query INNER join tables

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0

In my Joomla component I have two table:

Table1: #__com_units

```
 Id | Building | Floor |unit_number | posx | posy | mood
 -------------------------------------------------------
  1 | 01       | 01    | 001A       | 100 | 200   |Rented
  2 | 01       | 01    | 002A       | 101 | 202   |Available
  3 | 01       | 01    | 003A       | 102 | 204   |Available
  4 | 01       | 01    | 004A       | 103 | 206   |Available
  5 | 01       | 01    | 005A       | 104 | 208   |Rented
  6 | 01       | 01    | 006A       | 103 | 206   |Available
  7 | 01       | 01    | 007A       | 104 | 208   |Rented
  8 | 01       | 01    | 008A       | 103 | 206   |Rented
  9 | 01       | 01    | 009A       | 104 | 208   |Rented
 10 | 01       | 01    | 010A       | 103 | 206   |Available
```

Table1: #__com_reservations

```
 Id | Building | Floor |unit    | confirmation
 --------------------------------------------------
  1 | 01       | 01    | 002A   | NO
  2 | 01       | 01    | 003A   | YES
  3 | 01       | 01    | 004A   | NO
  4 | 01       | 01    | 006A   | NO
  5 | 01       | 01    | 010A   | YES
```

**i want to get query to show units as buttons which "mood=Rented" and "confirmation=YES"    but its not working:**

```
<?php
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

    $query->select($db->quoteName(array(
        'b.unit_number', 
        'a.confirmation',
        'b.posx',
        'b.id', 
        'a.unit', 
        'b.posy', 
        'b.mood'
    )));

    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__com_reservations','a' ))
              ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__com_units', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('b.unit_number') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('a.unit') . ')');

    $query->where($db->quoteName('b.floor')." = ".$db->quoteName('a.floor'),'AND')
          ->where($db->quoteName('b.building')." = ".$db->quoteName('a.building'),'AND')
          ->where($db->quoteName('a.confirmation')." = ".$db->quote('YES'));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo '<button class=" ' . $result->mood . ' ' . $result->posx . ' ' . $result->posy . '" value=' . $result->id . ' disabled> ' . $result->Unit_number  . '</button>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: format your code maybe?

Comment: @e4c5 code for single table works very well, i'm trying to get result for inner join with other table

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the Joomla but from your code it looks like you are trying to join `#__com_units` table with `#__com_reservations` using `#__com_units.unit_number` and `#__com_reservations.id`. Both fields have different data so you are not joining the tables properly. Tables should be joins using units field as `#__com_units.unit_number = #__com_reservations.unit_number`

Comment: You are right, corrected to `#__com_units.unit_number = #__com_reservations.unit` but still shows nothing.

Comment: What is the value in $db->quote('3')?

Comment: 3 is the value of yes in confirmation

Comment: check $db->quote('3') returns yes as 'YES' or 'yes'. If it is returning lowercase then you need to change it to upper case because your table contains confirmation as 'YES'.

Comment: update the value with YES instead of 3, but not worked.

Comment: Try removing $db->quote('YES') like this `->where($db->quoteName('#__com_reservations.confirmation')." = 'YES'");`

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT * FROM `#__com_reservations` A 
    JOIN `#__com_units` B
    ON A.unit = B.unit_number 
    AND A.building = B.building 
    AND A.floor = B.floor 
    WHERE A.confirmation = 'Yes' 
    AND B.mood = 'Available'
```

Even though i'm not familiar with joomla hope this mysql query will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
 ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__com_units', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('a.unit') . ')');
```